# How to apply TLS in Mosquitto with websockets?

Tags: ssl, websocket, mosquitto, paho, libwebsockets

I'm tring to test mosquitto+websocket broker.

My website that include mqtt-javacript use https, so i have to use wss:// protocol
So first I apply to broker TLS option(cafile, certfile, key), and it worked well.(not websockets)

But when i add websockets option in config file, It work only on ws:// protocol not wss://.

I don't know why TLS wasn't applied..... Somebody who know about this problem please help me...

```
port 1883
listener 9002
protocol websockets
cafile /etc/mosquitto/tls/ca.crt
certfile /etc/mosquitto/tls/server.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/tls/server.key
```

I followed steps to make CA and certificate file at http://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-tls-7.html